# Fade transition not working on React Bootstrap Alert component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have an alert which I display every time I load a page and the user can close the alert when ever he wants.

Now I want to add a closing transition to the alert but it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried a lot of things but still no transition effect on my alert.

Here is my code now:

```
function ReactTip(props){
    if(props.display){
        return(
            <Bs.Fade in={props.display}>
                <div>
                <Bs.Alert variant={props.variant} onClose={props.onClose} dismissible>
                    <FaLightbulb /> Tip: For multiple inputs, you can press tab while inside a text box to automatically add a new row.
                </Bs.Alert>
                </div>
            </Bs.Fade>
        );
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that the value of props.display is true. What is wrong with my code?

Update #1:
I tried this and the transition is working but the div is still there like the CSS display is set to hidden and not none.

```
return(
       <Bs.Fade in={props.display}>
           <div>
                <Bs.Alert variant={props.variant} onClose={props.onClose} dismissible>
                    <FaLightbulb /> Tip: For multiple inputs, you can press tab while inside a text box to automatically add a new row.
                </Bs.Alert>
           </div>
       </Bs.Fade>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a way to make the `<Fade />` work so I just used `<Collapse />`

Here is my updated code:

```
<Bs.Collapse in={props.display}>
    <div>
         <Bs.Alert variant={props.variant} onClose={props.onClose} dismissible>
            <FaLightbulb /> Tip: For multiple inputs, you can press tab while inside a text box to automatically add a new row.
         </Bs.Alert>
    </div>
</Bs.Collapse>
```

Comment: I can't get your example to work. When I click 'x' the Collapse moves up but then immediately drops back. I think something causes the Collapse to expand constantly, it can never shrink. My code: `<Collapse in={myVar}> <Alert ... onClose={() => setMyVar(!myVar) /> </Collapse>`

Answer (score 1):

Use the transition [prop](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/alerts/#alert-props) `transition={Fade}`.

Comment: {Fade} is not defined

Comment: transition={{ Fade }} @geneb.